# getting delay in serial communication between arduino nano and nodemcu

Tags: arduino, serial, delay, nodemcu

I am making a project of transformer health monitoring in which I am taking sensor data from an Arduino Nano to a Nodemcu and then uploading to Ubidots server.

The problem I am facing is that I am getting delay data in Nodemcu; I want to eliminate this delay.

**Arduino Nano code:**

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include "DHT.h" 

SoftwareSerial nodemcu(8, 9);
float sdata1 = 0; // sensor1 data
float sdata2 = 0; // sensor2 data
float sdata3 = 0; // sensor3 data
float sdata4 = 0; // sensor3 data
float sdata5 = 0; // sensor3 data

String cdata; // complete data, consisting of sensors values

//---------------------------------- Oil level --------------------------
const int trigPin = 5;
const int echoPin = 6;
long duration,hp = 0;
int distance;

//--------------------------------- Current measurement -----------------
const int currentPin = A0;
int sensitivity = 66;
int adcValue= 0;
int offsetVoltage = 2500;
double adcVoltage = 0;
double currentValue = 0;

//----------------------------------- Voltage measurement ---------------
const int voltageSensor = A1;

float vOUT = 0.0;
float vIN = 0.0;
float R1 = 30000.0;
float R2 = 7500.0;
int value = 0;

//------------------------------ Temperature and Humidity ----------------------
 #define DHTPIN 2     // Digital pin connected to the DHT sensor
 #define DHTTYPE DHT11   // DHT 11
 DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // Starts the serial communication
  nodemcu.begin(115200);
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT); // Sets the trigPin as an Output
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT); // Sets the echoPin as an Input
  dht.begin();
}

void loop() {
  //------------------------------- Oil level ----------------------------------
  // Clears the trigPin
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  // Sets the trigPin on HIGH state for 10 micro seconds
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  // Reads the echoPin, returns the sound wave travel time in microseconds
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  // Calculating the distance
  distance= duration*0.034/2;
  distance = distance -6;
  distance = 50 - distance;

  //-------------------------------- Current measurement -------------------------
  adcValue = analogRead(currentPin);
  adcVoltage = (adcValue / 1024.0) * 5000;
  currentValue = ((adcVoltage - offsetVoltage) / sensitivity);

  //------------------------------- Voltage Measurement --------------------------
  value = analogRead(voltageSensor);
  vOUT = (value * 5.0) / 1024.0;
  vIN = vOUT / (R2/(R1+R2));

  //------------------------------ Temperature and Humidity ----------------------
  delay(2000);
  // Reading temperature or humidity takes about 250 milliseconds!
  // Sensor readings may also be up to 2 seconds 'old' (its a very slow sensor)
  float h = dht.readHumidity();
  // Read temperature as Celsius (the default)
  float t = dht.readTemperature();
  sdata1 = (float)distance;
  sdata2 = (float)currentValue;
  sdata3 = vIN;
  sdata4 = h;
  sdata5 = t;

  cdata = cdata + sdata1+","+sdata2+","+sdata3+","+sdata4+","+sdata5; // comma will be used a 
 delimeter
  Serial.println(cdata); 
  nodemcu.println(cdata);
  delay(6000); // 100 milli seconds
  cdata = ""; 
}
```

**The nodemcu code :**

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include "Ubidots.h"

const char* UBIDOTS_TOKEN = "BBFF-u3oILXSLne0dKPzt2aoUtHarCkflDG"; // Put here your Ubidots TOKEN
const char* WIFI_SSID = "Said Ahmad2";  // Put here your Wi-Fi SSID
const char* WIFI_PASS = "24276016*";    // Put here your Wi-Fi password

Ubidots ubidots(UBIDOTS_TOKEN, UBI_HTTP);
String myString; // complete message from arduino, which consistors of snesors data
char rdata; // received charactors
float firstVal, secondVal,thirdVal,fourthVal,fifthVal; // sensors 

void setup() {
  // Debug console
  Serial.begin(115200);
  ubidots.wifiConnect(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASS);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0 ) {
    rdata = Serial.read(); 
    myString = myString+ rdata; 
    // Serial.print(rdata);
    if (rdata == '\n') {
      // new code
      String l = getValue(myString, ',', 0);
      String m = getValue(myString, ',', 1);
      String n = getValue(myString, ',', 2); 
      String o = getValue(myString, ',', 3);
      String p = getValue(myString, ',', 4);

      firstVal = l.toFloat();
      secondVal = m.toFloat();
      thirdVal = n.toFloat();
      fourthVal = o.toFloat();
      fifthVal = p.toFloat();
      Serial.print(firstVal);
      Serial.print(",");
      Serial.print(secondVal);
      Serial.print(",");
      Serial.print(thirdVal);
      Serial.print(",");
      Serial.print(fourthVal);
      Serial.print(",");
      Serial.print(fifthVal);

      ubidots.add("value1", firstVal);  // Change for your variable name
      ubidots.add("value2", secondVal);
      ubidots.add("value3", thirdVal);
      ubidots.add("value4", fourthVal);
      ubidots.add("value5", fifthVal);
      bool bufferSent = false;
      bufferSent = ubidots.send();  // Will send data to a device label that matches the device Id

      if (bufferSent) {
        // Do something if values were sent properly
        Serial.println("Values sent by the device");
      }

      delay(5000);
      myString = "";
      // end new code
    }
  }
}

String getValue(String data, char separator, int index) {
  int found = 0;
  int strIndex[] = { 0, -1 };
  int maxIndex = data.length() - 1;
 
  for (int i = 0; i <= maxIndex && found <= index; i++) {
    if (data.charAt(i) == separator || i == maxIndex) {
      found++;
      strIndex[0] = strIndex[1] + 1;
      strIndex[1] = (i == maxIndex) ? i+1 : i;
    }
  }
  return found > index ? data.substring(strIndex[0], strIndex[1]) : "";
}
```

Can anyone please help me out to get out of this delay problem?

Comment: remove delay(5000); ?

Comment: after removing i am getting 12 second delay

Comment: Where's the delay? In the sending to the Nodemcu, in the handling on the Nodemcu, or in the sending to the Ubidots server? Why are there 2 seconds and 6 seconds delay in the Arduino Nano code? BTW `delay(6000); // 100 milli seconds` delays 6000ms, not 100ms.